# unzip how to trim top directories

Tags: linux, zip

I have a zip archive. The `unzip -l myarchive.zip` command gives this listing:

```
top/subtop/files/1.txt
top/subtop/files2/2.txt
etc
```

The root folders are top/subtop for all files. How to extract those files without the two top/subtop folders?

E.g. when I am in /home/myuser/public_html directory, `files/1.txt` and `files2/2.txt` shoud be extracted directly to that directory.

I tried `unzip myarchive.zip top/subtop/*` but it created top/subtop directories anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Your only real option is to just move them after they are extracted.

Comment: Hmm, good to know. I asked this because a few days ago, when **creating** an archive, it was adding some paths from above, unintentionally. So there was a problem unzipping them because of the additional top paths. However, I can't repeat this today - today it's working ok, i.e. when in top/subtop directory and doing zip -r files.zip * it does **not** add the top/subtop path as prefix to files path. I think I do exactly the same command, but strangely, results are different, so it is not necessary to strip top directories when unzipping.

Comment: Note that it is possible to ignore all directories (simply placing all the files next to each other) with `unzip -j`.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try the `tar` command, which has a `--strip-components` feature and can operate on zip files.

Comment: Does not work with tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1: `tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors`

Comment: FreeBSD's tar can handle ZIP-archives. Other tar-implementations aren't as full-featured, unfortunately.

Comment: For debian users, FreeBSD's tar is available as bsdtar (apt-get install bsdtar) if you want to use tar to extract zip files.

Answer (score 1):

Using JMeter as an example:

```
# It's a good idea to set JMETER_HOME.
export JMETER_HOME=/usr/local/jmeter
unzip -q /tmp/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.zip -d $JMETER_HOME
for a in `ls -d -1 $JMETER_HOME/*`; do mv $a/* $JMETER_HOME; rmdir $a; done
```

Simple and portable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ unzip myarchive.zip
$ mv top/subtop/* .
```

Comment: It's too simple. You didn't extract the files with unzip

Answer (score -3):

I used this command to copy all files to my root file directory after Extracting All zipped files, it worked great.  Huge time saver:

```
for /r %f in (00P*) do @copy "%f"
```

(http://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/command-line-fun-how-to-flatten-a-folder-hierarchy/)

Comment: You do realize this is a DOS command, and has nothing to do with a Linux command line, right?